# What is the best way to do this site redirection

Tags: web-server, web-hosting, website, web, web-applications

Have a site in which we are pointing some links to `www.example1.com`.

Recently `www.example1.com` changed to `www.example2.com`.

Now if we access `www.example1.com` it will automatically redirect `www.example2.com`.

In `www.example.com` still it point to `www.example1.com`.

How its working now is...

`www.example.com` > `www.example.com` > `www.example1.com` > `www.example2.com`.

In our site all links are hard coded.

Question ?

What is the best way to do it ?

Continue to leave it like this or need to update all hard coded values.

Issue is : in future if we update this url again, we need to update code again

Please help me with some suggestions.

Comment: Stop hardcoding the site name into your links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirections should almost always only be used during transition and should be removed after a set period of time.  Ideally, you should not be using absolute links in your application.

This page provides a pretty good explanation: [Absolute vs. Relative Paths/Links](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)